# Color the gaps between stacked columns in Excel/ThinkCell

Tags: excel, ms-office, powerpoint, visualization, stacked-chart

Can I do that in Excel or PowerPoint, maybe with necessary add-ins like Think Cell? I wouldn't want to do that manually by using shapes or overlaying one type of chart over another.

An example of such chart from McKinsey research:

[image: img1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create such a chart I would assume that the author either colored it manually (not so unlikely if the picture is a one-off, consultancies have lots of people for such tasks) or used the following trick: The picture you showed consists of two charts (leaving the pillars on the right hand side out of scope):

1. The bar chart with all the numbers and texts in front
2. And in the background an area chart without numbers and texts

While 1) will only have columns for 2012, 2013, ... 2017 it is necessary that 2) is more granular and contain y-values for the following x-values 2012-left, 2012-right, 2013-left, 2013-right and so on.

In the end there will be quite some fine-tuning required.

All the best.

Jens